# Prevent different instances of object being updated at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple action in a controller that updates an object A:

`@a.update(params)`

Associated objects can be created with `accepts_nested_attributes`. For the sake of the example, in params we could have `b_ids: [1,2,3]`.

The associated object B has a `uniqueness` validation to ensure that is only associated once with object A. This works as expected in normal conditions.

*However*, this action is being executed by a JavaScript script, and for some reason (a bug I can't spot) is fired twice, which results in two simultaneous calls to the update action, which leads to duplicated associations being created.

I've read about transactions in Rails but I'm not sure this can be applied here. So my question is: **how can I avoid two different instances of a record happen at the same time?**

PS1: Of course, need to fix that JS script, but I guess this could still happen if two different users were updating the same object at the very same time…

PS2: I'm not even sure if I'm asking for the right thing… Sorry :-)

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803574/rails-implementing-a-simple-lock-to-prevent-users-from-editing-the-same-data ? You can use a lock to create a mutual exclusion area.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielMesquita. Having a look :-)

Comment: You should also add unique constraint on DB level. Something like `add_index :join_table_name, [:a_id, :b_id], unique: true`